How do I get rid of these "facetime links" that pollute Facetime?
These little bastards are created from times to times.
I don't want to see them created anymore. How?


Are you creating them or are others adding you to their chain? If I find a way to eliminate them , I’ll post but for now you might have to cope somehow (tap edit top left and delete them and it will warn you that others will lose the link if you created it afaik)

no, I am not creating anything and I doubt the people I talk are doing so. These are annoying. I see these being created for years

I have zero for 2 years of history in the app

very strange... I deleted these 3 yesterday. Today I have 2 more.

You might have to disable iCloud call history sync if these are coming from another of your FaceTime capable devices

icloud call history sync? where is it?

iCloud in settings app, saved to iCloud, toggle FaceTime. You should be able to search in settings too for FaceTime to locate things

the settings you mention were disabled
